# How many headers for a c-module?

Tags: c

I have a module in my project `mymodule.c` that provides a lot of functions for the rest of my project.
These function are defined in a `mymodule.h` header file.

But in `mymodule.c` there are a lot of other defines or define masks.

For example:

```
#define STACKSIZE 1024
#define TIMER1    100
#define TCR_MASK  16U
#define TCR       16U
#define TCR_IR    (0ULL << 8)
...
100 other defines or typedefs
```

I could split it up like this:

`mymodule.h`  --->all external functions and declarations used from other places.
Rename this to `mymodule_public.h` ?

`mymodule_config.h` ---> configuration like timers, controlparameters or constants.

`mymodule_masks.h`  ---> decsriptors.

There could be more headers.

Another way is to keep all except the external functions in the `mymodule.c`.

What is best practice for splitting up into headers and giving header names?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to stackoverflow :) Since there's not really a right or wrong answer to your question, you may be better off trying at https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Although even there, I see this warning about "best practices" questions which don't provide objective criteria for judging: https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8965/why-questions-about-the-correct-way-are-too-broad

Comment: @PaulHankin In my experience, questions aren't on-topic at softwareengineering. I wouldn't recommend anyone to use it. As for no right or wrong, only part of the question is subjective. #defines used internally should definitely not be placed in a public API header, that's not subjective, that's simply how you write programs.

Comment: Ok so this got closed. Turns out Stack Exchange has no site suitable for discussing program design. Which is incredibly weird, since 100% of all programmers need to discuss that somewhere. I would highly recommend to ask these questions at https://software.codidact.com/ instead. This community has explicitly decided to be more lenient towards program design questions, they are perfectly fine and on-topic there.

Comment: @PaulHankin: Thanks. I wasnt aware of the softwareengineering section. Ill take a look next time.

Comment: @parthagas That site will only close your question too. Software engineering isn't on-topic at softwareengineering.stackexchange.com. I deleted my account there many years ago, since nobody there knows what's on topic on the site, including the moderators themselves. Questions get nuked arbitrary/at a whim by individuals.

Comment: @Lundin Thanks for your link. I will read up there too.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, a header file which is the public interface of a library should contain all the things that the caller needs to use the functions.

If you have a bunch of `#define` that are necessary to use the functions, they need to be in the h file. If they aren't needed but just used internally, you should keep them in the c file.

It is ok to make a 2nd header file which isn't the public API but just contains internal constants used by your c file(s).

As for where to place the #includes, that's a bit subjective. Generally I like to show the user of the library which dependencies the library comes with, so that they can ensure that they have all the necessary files and so that they can trouble-shoot strange linker errors easier. On the other hand, one might feel uneasy about "exposing" includes that are just used privately by the library in the public header (like the 2nd private header mentioned above). There's no obvious right or wrong here, though try to be consistent with where you place the #includes.

Your idea with multiple headers all named with a certain library-specific prefix "mymodule" is pretty sound overall.

Comment: I try to create a template for my modules and how many headers are used and their name conventions. Only having one headerfile for public api would be most cleaned up solution. But on the other hand, 100 #defines for internally use in the c file is annoying me. I think i will start with two or three headerfiles in my module. How do you call your public api headerfile of a `mymodule.c` , `mymodule.h` ?

Comment: @parthagas If there's a tonne of defines but they are only used by one single .c file then I wouldn't worry about them being numerous and just place them in that .c file. The public header file should ideally be named whatever you call your library. So if this the "My module library" then `mymodule.h` sounds good. Note however that such a header could have more than one corresponding .c file, for larger projects.